# VHDL: FSM output delayed of 1 clock cycle

Tags: vhdl, fsm

i'm currently writing some vhdl code and i got a problem with an FSM.
In particular, the FSM is quite simple, it's got just 3 states, S0, S1, S2.
Here's the code:

```
type state is (S0,S1,S2);
signal state_curr, state_next : state;
begin
    process(i_clk,i_rst)
    begin
        if i_rst = '1' then
            state_next <= S0;
            state_curr <= state_next;
        elsif rising_edge(i_clk) then
            state_curr <= state_next;
            
            case state_curr is
                
                when S0 =>
                    out_sample_first = '0'
                    out_sample_second = '0'
                    if first_input = '1' then
                        state_next <= S1;
                    else 
                        state_next <= S0;
                    end if;       
            
                when S1 =>  
                    out_sample_first = '1'
                    out_sample_second = '0'
                    if second_input = '1' then
                        state_next <= S2;
                    else 
                        state_next <= S1;
                    end if;       
                    
                 when S2 =>
                    out_sample_first = '0'
                    out_sample_second = '1'
                    if first_input = '0' and second_input = '0' then
                        state_next <= S0;
                    else 
                        state_next <= S2;
                    end if;    
             
            end case;
        end if;        
    end process;
```

The transitions between states work fine, but it's the two output signals that i have problem with.
Specifically, it takes a full clock cycle to "update" those signals.
Here's an example (took from a testbench i wrote).

On the first few clock cycles, my FSM is in S0 and out_sample_first is 0, while out_sample_second is 0, as it should be.
At the clock cycle number 10, first_input becomes 1.
Naturally, it takes 1 clock cycle to transition to S1 and, correctly, on the rising edge of clock cycle 11, the FSM is in state S1.
My problem is here: i expected out_sample_first to be 1 and out_sample_second to be 0 (which are the expected output of the FSM in the S1 state), but in this clock cycle number 11 the signals are the same of the previous cycle.
Then, at clock cycle 12, the signals change and, correctly, they go to out_sample_first = 1 and out_sample_second = 0.

I wanna understand why this happens and, since the FSM works in conjunction with a counter, it's crucial that this delay doesn't happen. What can i do about it?

My first "solution" was to change `case state_curr is` in `case state_next is`
which, as the test bench shows, works fine. I'm not sure this is the "optimal solution" or a solution at all tho.

Comment: Do you have a specific programming question? You don't provide a [mcve] only a process statement, two declarations and no testbench. Your problem can't be replicated meaning `What can i do about it?` is abstract. You have a solution that is not demonstrable nor is what you mean by "optimal solution" defined. You have expressions in case statement alternatives in a place for sequential statements, these will produce syntax errors. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Pragmatically if those expressions are intended to assignment statements (to out_sample_first and out_sample_second, both missing declarations) comment all those out of the shown process statement and use concurrent conditional assignment (e.g. out_sample_first = '1' when state_curr = S1 else '0'; out_sample_second <= '1' when state_curr = S2 else '0';) Imagine the state being one hot and the same type as the outputs. There'd be no logic and no output flip flops.

Comment: In the single process form of state machine, you only have one State signal, not separate ones for current and next. This might be all you need to fix.